# How to group data from an API response in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I wanted grab some data from an API result and make the grouping to make if readable. The url I need to grab is `https://api.testnet.minepi.com/accounts/GCMWJ5FHNS6VFMIY34IL55YCQEJCGWYWUBKDRAEA3KS7DHRIPRA37P7D#payments`. There are 55 total incoming and outgoing transactions made.

I also do not understand this part of the url `{?cursor,limit,order}`
`https://api.testnet.minepi.com/accounts/GCMWJ5FHNS6VFMIY34IL55YCQEJCGWYWUBKDRAEA3KS7DHRIPRA37P7D/transactions{?cursor,limit,order}`

Initial Code:

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0',}
url =  f"https://api.testnet.minepi.com/accounts/GCMWJ5FHNS6VFMIY34IL55YCQEJCGWYWUBKDRAEA3KS7DHRIPRA37P7D/payments?0,300,asc"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers,timeout=timeoutReq).json()
print (response)
```

Needed Output Sample: #-- All transactions

```
Outgoing Transactions: 
amount: 5.0000000     ->  to: GA6DJZLKRPWATZVGKZEKBGEX4CHJYBSRNPDBIQ3RUCC3RW3XVL2EZ6XF
amount: 3.0000000     ->  to: GCMWJ5FHNS6VFMIY34IL55YCQEJCGWYWUBKDRAEA3KS7DHRIPRA37P7D

Total Outgoing: 2
Total Amount:   8.0000000

Incoming Transactions: 
amount:  5.1000000    ->  from: 'GD3TTNZ47C4CTJM6A6O7AU7YVQOJN6YEFBYWDKNLCJFOFSXEEPK5WYMN'
amount: 15.0000000    ->  from: 'GD3TTNZ47C4CTJM6A6O7AU7YVQOJN6YEFBYWDKNLCJFOFSXEEPK5WYMN'
amount: 25.2000000    ->  from: 'GD3TTNZ47C4CTJM6A6O7AU7YVQOJN6YEFBYWDKNLCJFOFSXEEPK5WYMN'
amount: 35.0000000    ->  from: 'GD3TTNZ47C4CTJM6A6O7AU7YVQOJN6YEFBYWDKNLCJFOFSXEEPK5WYMN'
amount: 45.5000000    ->  from: 'GD3TTNZ47C4CTJM6A6O7AU7YVQOJN6YEFBYWDKNLCJFOFSXEEPK5WYMN'

Total Incoming:   5
Total Amount:   125.8000000
```

Current Output:

```
{'_links': {'self': {'href': 'https://api.testnet.minepi.com/accounts/GCMWJ5FHNS6VFMIY34IL55YCQEJCGWYWUBKDRAEA3KS7DHRIPRA37P7D/payments?0%2C300%2Casc=&cursor=&limit=10&order=asc'}, 'next': {'href': 'https://api.testnet.minepi.com/accounts/GCMWJ5FHNS6VFMIY34IL55YCQEJCGWYWUBKDRAEA3KS7DHRIPRA37P7D/payments?0%2C300%2Casc=&cursor=17860118989250561&limit=10&order=asc'}, 'prev': {'href': 'https://api.testnet.minepi.com/accounts/GCMWJ5FHNS6VFMIY34IL55YCQEJCGWYWUBKDRAEA3KS7DHRIPRA37P7D/payments?0%2C300%2Casc=&cursor=15670488827207681&limit=10&order=desc'}},

#-- more lines below
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the account of interest, which in this case is the one you are using in the URL: `GCMWJ5FHNS6VFMIY34IL55YCQEJCGWYWUBKDRAEA3KS7DHRIPRA37P7D`, you can use it to compare with the data in each record you get from the API and group them as you want.

In your case, you want to group them by `outgoing` and `incoming`, so you can compare with the properties `from` and `to`, in the response data. If the account of interest is in the `from` property, it means that it should be grouped in the `outgoing` group. If it is in the `to` property, it should be grouped in the `incoming` group.

There are many different approaches to grouping the records. A simple one would be to create 2 lists: `payments_received` and `payments_sent`. It should be something like this:

```py
import requests

account = "GCMWJ5FHNS6VFMIY34IL55YCQEJCGWYWUBKDRAEA3KS7DHRIPRA37P7D"
timeoutReq = 5000
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0'
}
url = f"https://api.testnet.minepi.com/accounts/{account}/payments?0,300,asc"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers,timeout=timeoutReq).json()

# create lists to store the transactions we want
payments_sent = []
payments_received = []

# iterate over the records in the response
for record in response["_embedded"]["records"]:
    # we are interested in the "payment" types
    if record["type"] == "payment":
        if record["from"] == account:
            payments_sent.append(record)
        elif record["to"] == account:
            payments_received.append(record)

print(f"Number of payments received: {len(payments_received)}")

print("---")

print(f"Number of payments sent: {len(payments_sent)}")
```

You can see it in action here: https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/python-3-nN1xfb

Once you have this data grouped, you can iterate over each list and present the data as you want it.

The `{?cursor,limit,order}` in the URL are parameters that can be used to paginate and sort the data you get from the API. You can see that the values for `?cursor,limit,order` have been defined to `0,300,asc` in the URL you make a request to: `https://api.testnet.minepi.com/accounts/{account}/payments?0,300,asc`
I also think that the `{}` inform that they are optional. But I am not sure.

UPDATE: how to iterate over the grouped records

To iterate over the records list and print the data you want, you can use a simple `for` loop, like:

```py
print(f"Number of payments received: {len(payments_received)}")
for payment in payments_received:
    print(f"amount: {payment['amount']} -> from: {payment['from']}")

print("---")

print(f"Number of payments sent: {len(payments_sent)}")
for payment in payments_sent:
    print(f"amount: {payment['amount']} -> to: {payment['to']}")
```

Comment: how to display this ` amount: 5.0000000     ->  to: GA6DJZLKRPWATZVGKZEKBGEX4CHJYBSRNPDBIQ3RUCC3RW3XVL2EZ6XF`

Comment: I have updated the comment with an example, @errzoned